How do unique instances of CounterView?
The plus and minus on the first two Views dont work only the last one. The buttons on I have a view that is inside a ForLoop all the information in the View is coming from a Data struct. I feel as if Ive narrowed the problem down to the fact that the far most view is the in the ForLoop is the "Original" instance
// Home page

//
//  ContentView.swift
//  
//
//  Created on 5/25/24.
//

import SwiftUI

struct Home: View {
    @State private var data: [Dataa] = MockData.data
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack{
            ScrollView(.horizontal){
                VStack{
                    HStack{
                        ForEach(data.indices, id: \.self){ num in
                            VStack{
                               
                                CounterView(data: $data[num])
                                    
                                

                            }
                            
                        }
                    }
                    
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Home")
            .toolbar{
              
                ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarLeading){
                    Image("placeholder")
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 65, height: 65)
                        .cornerRadius(3)
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
}

#Preview {
    Home()
}


// Counter View

//
//  CounterView.swift
// 
//
//  Created on 5/26/24.
//

import SwiftUI


struct CounterView: View {
    @Binding var data: Dataa
    
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            Rectangle()
                .frame(width: 200, height: 275)
                .cornerRadius(20)
                .foregroundColor(.indigo)
            VStack{
                Image("placeholder")
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                    .scaledToFill()
                    .clipShape(Circle())
                    
                Text("placeholder")
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                    .padding(.vertical, 35)
                
                HStack{
                    // Minus Button
                    Button{
                        self.data.numero -= 1
                    } label: {
                        Image(systemName:"minus")
                            .foregroundColor(.gray)
                            .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                    }
                    // Rectangles and TextFields
                    VStack{
                        ZStack{
                            Rectangle()
                                .frame(width: 105, height: 30)
                                .cornerRadius(5)
                            Text("\(self.data.numero)")
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                                .frame(width: 105, height: 30)
                        }
                        ZStack{
                            Rectangle()
                                .frame(width: 105, height: 30)
                                .cornerRadius(5)
                            Text("\(self.data.numero)")
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                                .frame(width: 105, height: 30)
                                .clipped()

                            
                        }
                    }
                    // Minus Button
                    Button{
                        self.data.numero += 1
                    } label: {
                        Image(systemName:"plus")
                            .foregroundColor(.gray)
                            .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
    
}

#Preview {
    CounterView(data:.constant(Dataa(numero: 0, image: "")))
}

// Data

//
//  Data.swift
//  
//
//  Created on 5/26/24.
//

import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct Dataa: Hashable, Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    
    var numero: Int
    let image: String
}


struct MockData{
    
    static let sampleView = Dataa(numero: 0, image: "placeholder")
    
    
    static let data = [
        Dataa(numero: 3, image: "placeholder"),
    
        Dataa(numero: 2, image: "placeholder"),
    
        Dataa(numero: 1, image: "placeholder")]
}

Ive tried a variety of things. At first I thought it was a UI bug and spent 30 minutes trying to debug my UI. After this it was a jumble of things i kept on trying

Although your code works for me, I recommend using
ForEach($data){ $dat in      VStack {          CounterView(data: $dat)      }  } instead of using indices.

@workingdogsupportUkraine Hello, Do the first two in CounterViews in the homepage work? Also when I try to use CounterView(data: $dat) i get the error "Cannot convert value of type 'Binding<[Dataa]>.Element' (aka 'Binding') to expected argument type 'Dataa'"

@workingdogsupportUkraine when putting it in a different project it works I will try and see what I did wrong in my original code. Thank you!

Try this approach using bindings in the ForEach($data){ $dat in ...}
instead of using indices.
struct Home: View {
    @State private var data: [Dataa] = MockData.data 
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack{
            ScrollView(.horizontal){
                VStack{
                    HStack{
                        ForEach($data){ $dat in  // <--- here `$`
                            VStack {
                                CounterView(data: $dat)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Home")
            .toolbar{
                ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarLeading){
                    Image(systemName: "info")
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 65, height: 65)
                        .cornerRadius(3)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

EDIT-1
Here is my full code that works for me.
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Home()
    }
}

struct Home: View {
    @State private var data: [Dataa] = MockData.data
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack{
            ScrollView(.horizontal){
                VStack{
                    HStack{
                        ForEach($data){ $dat in  // <--- here `$`
                            VStack {
                                CounterView(data: $dat)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Home")
            .toolbar{
                ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarLeading){
                    Image(systemName: "info")
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 65, height: 65)
                        .cornerRadius(3)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct CounterView: View {
    @Binding var data: Dataa

    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            Rectangle()
                .frame(width: 200, height: 275)
                .cornerRadius(20)
                .foregroundColor(.indigo)
            VStack{
                Image(systemName: "globe")
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                    .scaledToFill()
                    .clipShape(Circle())
                    
                Text("placeholder")
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                    .padding(.vertical, 35)
                
                HStack{
                    // Minus Button
                    Button{
                        self.data.numero -= 1
                    } label: {
                        Image(systemName: "minus")
                            .foregroundColor(.gray)
                            .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                    }
                    // Rectangles and TextFields
                    VStack{
                        ZStack{
                            Rectangle()
                                .frame(width: 105, height: 30)
                                .cornerRadius(5)
                            Text("\(self.data.numero)")
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                                .frame(width: 105, height: 30)
                        }
                        ZStack{
                            Rectangle()
                                .frame(width: 105, height: 30)
                                .cornerRadius(5)
                            Text("\(self.data.numero)")
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                                .frame(width: 105, height: 30)
                                .clipped()
                        }
                    }
                    // Minus Button
                    Button{
                        self.data.numero += 1
                    } label: {
                        Image(systemName: "plus")
                            .foregroundColor(.gray)
                            .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
}

struct Dataa: Hashable, Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    
    var numero: Int
    let image: String
}

struct MockData{
    static let sampleView = Dataa(numero: 0, image: "placeholder")

    static let data = [
        Dataa(numero: 3, image: "placeholder"),
        Dataa(numero: 2, image: "placeholder"),
        Dataa(numero: 1, image: "placeholder")]
}


I get the error "Cannot convert value of type 'Binding<[Dataa]>.Element' (aka 'Binding') to expected argument type 'Dataa'"

update my answer with the code that works for me. Tested on real ios devices and MacCatalyst. Try my full code and let me know if you still get an error.

if my answer helped you, consider accepting it by ticking the tick mark next to it, it turns green.
